# Bash - move files with similar name from multiple directories to pwd

Tags: linux, bash, mingw

Say I have directories:

```
mydir1
mydir2
mydir3
mydir4
```

containing files starting with `abcd`

I'd like to move all file beginning with `abcd` to the parent directory. How can I do this?

Here's what I've been playing with:

```
for file in pwd; mv *abcd ../
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cd to the parent directory, then:

```
for f in */abcd*;
do mv $f ./
done
```

that will match `mydir1/abcdfoo`, `mydir2/abcdbar` etc. and move them to the pwd (which is the parent directory). If you only want to look in directories called mydir* you could specify

```
for f in mydir*/abcd*; 
do mv $f ./
done
```

You could also do

```
find . -name "abcd*" -type f -exec mv {} ./ \;
```

that finds all the regular files (not dirs) named abcd* and moves them to the pwd. Find looks recursively from the directory you specify after the find command, that's "." in this case. You can use absolute paths like:

```
find /path/to/the/parent/dir -name "abcd*" -type f -exec mv {} /path/to/the/destination/dir/ \;
```

**WARNING**: I just noticed this when I tried it. If there are multiple files with the same name in different directories e.g. mydir1/abcdfoo, mydir2/abcdfoo and so on, all but one of them will be overwritten, leaving you with just one abcdfoo file in the parent directory.

Comment: Thanks, I got the following error when using your first suggestion `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'mv'`. The second suggestion worked though...

Comment: Ah, yes, I tested it in zsh, where the for loops don't need a "do". I'll amend the answer.